# How to write a wave-fuction of bose einstein condesate bosons in second quantization representation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, second-quantization, bose-einstein-condensate

Can we write wave function of bose einstein condensation like this $|\psi \rangle=\frac{{c^{\dagger}}^N}{ \sqrt{N!}} |0\rangle$. Or it will be different?

Answer (score 0):

In second quantisation, you would write it as:

$$ |\mathrm{BEC}\rangle   = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N!}}(a^\dagger_0)^N\,|0\rangle, $$ 
where $a^\dagger_0$ is the (bosonic) creation operator for the $\mathbf{k} = 0$ state.